# How can I reduce boilerplate from this function?

Tags: javascript, oop, qooxdoo

In my qooxdoo application I have 4 buttons. Login, logout, register and profile. Every button has an action class. Those classes are subclassed from a common abstract class. By using the command pattern I call the execute function of the according class every time a button is clicked.  The function looks like this

```
    execute: function() {
        var contentString = "login-form";
         //do some generic stuff

        if (win.getContentString() === contentString) {
          //do some generic stuff

        } else {
            var content = new myapp.apps.userActions.SLoginForm();
            //do some more generic stuff

        }
    }
```

That execute function has to be implemented in all 4 subclasses and the only things that change are the variables content and contentString.

I am thinking of using a factory function and every time return the appropriate object based on the contentString variable.

```
execute:function(){
    var contentString = "login-form";
    this.doTheGenericStuff(contentString);
},

doTheGenericStuff: function(contentString){
    //do the generic stuff
    var content = this.getTheObject(contentString);
    //do some more generic stuff
},

getTheObject: function(contentString){
    switch(contentString){
          case "login-form": 
               return new myapp.apps.userActions.SLoginForm();
          break;
          case "register-form":
               return new myapp.apps.userActions.SRegisterForm();
          break;
          //etc
    }
}
```

While this seems ok (haven't tested it yet) I don't like it much because every time I add new actions I have to update the factory function. Is there any more clever way to achieve this? Maybe some feature of javascript that I don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the use of [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) is more appropriate in this case.

So on your abstract class your have:

```
getMyContentString: function() { return "login-form"; //or any default value },

getMyContent: function() { return new myapp.apps.userActions.SLoginForm() },

execute: function() {
        var contentString = getMyContentString(); // to be overridden
         //do some generic stuff

        if (win.getContentString() === contentString) {
          //do some generic stuff

        } else {
            var content = getMyContent();
            //do some more generic stuff

        }
    }
```

And each child object just need to provide the appropriate `getMyContentString()` and `getMyContent()`

Answer (score 1):

Minor point, but you don't need to have `break` statements for each `case` if you already have a `return` statement, as that is enough to exist the `switch`.

You could pass an extra parameter, and use it to call the constructor using bracket notation instead of dot notation.

```
execute:function(){
    var contentString = "login-form";
    var objectType = "SLoginForm";
    this.doTheGenericStuff(contentString, objectType);
},

doTheGenericStuff: function(contentString, objectType){
    //do the generic stuff
    var content = this.getTheObject(objectType);
    //do some more generic stuff
},

getTheObject: function(objectType){
    return new myapp.apps.userActions[objectType]();
}
```